# Adding a new level to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have created a dataframe that looks as follow:

```
df= 
        id      var0    var1    var2    var3    var4 ...  var137
        5171    10.0    2.8     0.0     5.0     1.0  ...  9.4  
        5171    40.9    2.5     3.4     4.5     1.3  ...  7.7  
        5171    60.7    3.1     5.2     6.6     3.4  ...  1.0
        ...
        5171    0.5     1.3     5.1     0.5     0.2  ...  0.4
        4567    1.5     2.0     1.0     4.5     0.1  ...  0.4  
        4567    4.4     2.0     1.3     6.4     0.1  ...  3.3  
        4567    6.3     3.0     1.5     7.6     1.6  ...  1.6
        ...
        4567    0.7     1.4     1.4     0.3     4.2  ...  1.7
       ... 
        9584    0.3     2.6     0.0     5.2     1.6  ...  9.7  
        9584    0.5     1.2     8.3     3.4     1.3  ...  1.7  
        9584    0.7     3.0     5.6     6.6     3.0  ...  1.0
        ...
        9584    0.7     1.3     0.1     0.0     2.0  ...  1.7
```

There are 58 items of `id` level. I need to add a new level, lets call id `uniq_id` to this dataframe so that the final result be as follow:

```
df= 
  uniq_id      id      var0    var1    var2    var3    var4 ...  var137
    0          5171    10.0    2.8     0.0     5.0     1.0  ...  9.4  
    1          5171    40.9    2.5     3.4     4.5     1.3  ...  7.7  
    2          5171    60.7    3.1     5.2     6.6     3.4  ...  1.0
   ...
   57          5171    0.5     1.3     5.1     0.5     0.2  ...  0.4
    0          4567    1.5     2.0     1.0     4.5     0.1  ...  0.4  
    1          4567    4.4     2.0     1.3     6.4     0.1  ...  3.3  
    2          4567    6.3     3.0     1.5     7.6     1.6  ...  1.6
    ...
   57          4567    0.7     1.4     1.4     0.3     4.2  ...  1.7
    ... 
    0          9584    0.3     2.6     0.0     5.2     1.6  ...  9.7  
    1          9584    0.5     1.2     8.3     3.4     1.3  ...  1.7  
    2          9584    0.7     3.0     5.6     6.6     3.0  ...  1.0
    ...
    57         9584    0.7     1.3     0.1     0.0     2.0  ...  1.7
```

I tried this:

```
n_t = range(0,58)
pd.concat([df], keys=n, names=['uniq_id'])
```

but this adds 0 to all values fot `uniq_id`. I also tried to create an empty `multiindex` based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28289440/creating-an-empty-multiindex) and then get part of dataframe for each `id` and add it to this `multiIndex` one but I failed. How can I fix it?

Comment: Would a cumulative count solve your problem? `df['uniq_id'] = df.groupby('id').cumcount()`

Comment: are the number of rows always a multiple of 58?

Comment: I think @Jondiedoop should be an answer

Comment: @Jondiedoop that adds a new column to the dataframe. I need to add a new index/level to it

Comment: @Oswald yes all id's have the same size

Comment: @Birish, I've tried to edit my answer to solve this problem and make it an index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You describe a [cumulative count](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df['uniq_id'] = df.groupby('id').cumcount()
```

You can add it to the index by

```
df.set_index(['id', 'uniq_id']) # If id was a Series
```

or if `id` is already the index:

```
df.set_index('uniq_id', append=True) # If id was already an Index
```

which will give you a MultiIndex:
Output:

```
    var0  var1  var2  var3  var4  var137
id   uniq_id                                      
5171 0        10.0   2.8   0.0   5.0   1.0     9.4
     1        40.9   2.5   3.4   4.5   1.3     7.7
     2        60.7   3.1   5.2   6.6   3.4     1.0
     3         0.5   1.3   5.1   0.5   0.2     0.4
4567 0         1.5   2.0   1.0   4.5   0.1     0.4
     1         4.4   2.0   1.3   6.4   0.1     3.3
     2         6.3   3.0   1.5   7.6   1.6     1.6
     3         0.7   1.4   1.4   0.3   4.2     1.7
9584 0         0.3   2.6   0.0   5.2   1.6     9.7
     1         0.5   1.2   8.3   3.4   1.3     1.7
     2         0.7   3.0   5.6   6.6   3.0     1.0
     3         0.7   1.3   0.1   0.0   2.0     1.7
```